# Timer and exception handling in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I had  strange issue with  below mentioned code. I don't understand what is the exact issue. Below code is part of windows service. This code is calling one com class function to perform some operation on message queue after fixed interval.
I have used System.threading.timer for this purpose. After start, service is working fine for some time but after some time it's  stopped working.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using CareMC.VBWrapper.RCWQueue;

namespace MSPQueueService
{
    public partial class MSPQueueService : ServiceBase
    {
        static System.Threading.Timer timer;
        const int TIMEOUTVALUE = 5000;
        private int isBusy = 0;
        public MSPQueueService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                AppendToLog("ONStart Begin");
                //Handle Elapsed event

                TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(OnElapsedTime);

                timer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, null, TIMEOUTVALUE, TIMEOUTVALUE);
                //EVENT _objEvent = new EVENT();
                //_objEvent.ExecuteMSPQueue();
                AppendToLog("ONStart End");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
                AppendToLog(ErrorMessage);
            }

        }

        private void OnElapsedTime(object state)
        {

            //If the isBusy value is 0 then replace it with 1 and continue otherwise it has already been incremented so we're already running

            //the handler so skip out

            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isBusy, 1, 0) != 0)
            {
                AppendToLog("OnElapsedTime is already running. isBusy=" + isBusy.ToString());
                return;
            }

            try
            {

                EVENT _objEvent = new EVENT();
                AppendToLog("Before Executing ExecuteMSPQueue function.");
                _objEvent.ExecuteMSPQueue();
                AppendToLog("After Executing ExecuteMSPQueue function.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppendToLog(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                AppendToLog("Resetting  isBusy value to 0=");
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref isBusy, 0);
                AppendToLog("Value of   isBusy  after reset =" + isBusy);

            };

        }


}
```

Here is smaple log from the code

> 10/11/2011 4:15:03 AM: Before Executing ExecuteMSPQueue function.
>
> 10/11/2011 4:15:08 AM: OnElapsedTime is already running.
>
> 10/11/2011 4:15:13 AM: OnElapsedTime is already running.
>
> 10/11/2011 4:15:18 AM: OnElapsedTime is already running.
>
> 10/11/2011 4:15:19 AM: After Executing ExecuteMSPQueue function.
>
> 10/11/2011 4:15:28 AM: OnElapsedTime is already running.
>
> 10/11/2011 4:15:33 AM: OnElapsedTime is already running.
>
> 10/11/2011 4:15:38 AM: OnElapsedTime is already running.
>
> 10/11/2011 4:15:43 AM: OnElapsedTime is already running.
>
> 10/11/2011 4:15:48 AM: OnElapsedTime is already running.
>
> 10/11/2011 4:15:53 AM: OnElapsedTime is already running.

This means value of IsBusy variable remains 1 and not reseting to 0 . by looking at  code it is only possible if there is exception which not gets caught in catch block.(is this possible?)

Please help me.

Comment: I think you should shorten your rather long code to the actual lines that you think are erroneous. Otherwise it's a "TL;DR" posting in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The timer will fire whether or not the previous run has finished.  If OnElapsedTime takes more than 5 seconds to run, the value will still be 1 when the timer executes again.

The callback delegate is called from threadpool threads, so this specific case is possible.

From MSDN:

> The method specified for callback should be reentrant, because it is
>   called on ThreadPool threads. The method can be executed
>   simultaneously on two thread pool threads if the timer interval is
>   less than the time required to execute the method, or if all thread
>   pool threads are in use and the method is queued multiple times.

EDIT:

Per the comment, given the fact that your *finally* block is never running, I'd guess that your thread that logged "After Executing" is still hung or deadlocked, either on the logging method, or possibly EVENT's finalizer (if it has one).  This is where stepping through with a debugger would probably be very enlightening.

Comment: Yes currently this is happening,  OnElapsedTime  fires multiple times before completion of last run. that's why I am checking the value of IsBusy variable.But if you look at the log 10/11/2011 4:15:19 AM: After Executing ExecuteMSPQueue function. I am expecting value of  IsBusy variable should reset to 0. whichis not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of your logging method, you may have concurrent problems there which might be causing the issues you are experiencing. Depending on your requirements, I would redesign your service using a Thread + Thread.Sleep().

Comment: Good point ,Logging may cause issue here.Let me change my logging code and let see if it work or not